# Why is only half the box showing up for box plot using R and ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to view some information I have amassed using a box-plot. However, I can't understand why 4 of the 6 groups only seem to have one box and not two.

Code I am using is farly straight forward.

```
sleepData %>% group_by(edu)
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: If you look carefully, you see that the median is highlighted, though...

Comment: There may be many values repeated at the mean (3) and  so the median _is_ the first quartile.  Check with `table(sleepData$healthScore, sleepData$edu)`

Comment: @G5W I think you're right! Thanks man for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your box plot looks like this is that the median (the 50th percentile, represented by the thicker black line that usually runs through the body of the box plot) and the 75th percentile (or the 25 percentile which are usually the upper and lower bonds of the rectangular body of the box plot) have exactly the same value. I try to illustrate the same thing with the example below.

```r
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))

df <- data.frame(one_box = c(1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6),
                 two_boxes = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

df %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise(prob = list(c("25%", "50%", "75%")), 
            quant = list(quantile(value, probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.5)))) %>%
  unnest()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>         key  prob quant
#>       <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1   one_box   25%  2.75
#> 2   one_box   50%  5.00
#> 3   one_box   75%  5.00
#> 4 two_boxes   25%  2.25
#> 5 two_boxes   50%  3.50
#> 6 two_boxes   75%  3.50

df %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(key, value)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]